# select multi column from stored procedures form dataGridview

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

stored procedures as follows :

```
    Create Procedure tblProfile_SelectAll
As
Begin
    Select 
        [name],
        [family]
    From tblProfile
End
```

I'm working with LinqToSql

The following code shows all fields.

```
    using (var c = new contextDataContext())
    {
        var query = c.tblProfile_SelectAll();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
    }
```

How to display only the name field?

Without changing the stored procedures

Comment: Also, can you start marking some of your answers as answered?  Otherwise there is little incentive to help.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the design time properties of the DataGridView.  Set AutoGenerateColumns to false and add a single text column for name.

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = query.Select(q => new {name = q.name}).ToList();
```